# What's the disadvantage of using Microsoft SQL Server Jobs for Backup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

I happen to find a lot of Automated SQL Backup Solutions on the net. two in particular are
- SQL Backup and FTP (http://sqlbackupandftp.com/)
- SQL Maintenance Solutions (http://ola.hallengren.com/)

My question, why do people use these solutions when SQL already has SQL Server Jobs Agent which can do this for them?

Comment: You'll probably get a better response on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another popular one you didn't mention is Red Gate's SQL Backup Pro - [Here's their sales pitch](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/), and I'm assuming the products you mention will have similar pitches.

> Why SQL Backup Pro?
>
> Save time and space: compress SQL Server backups by up to 95% for
> faster, smaller backups
>
> Strengthen SQL Server backup and restore
> activities: use network resilience for backups, restores and log
> shipping
>
> Protect your data: use up to 256-bit AES encryption to secure
> your data against unauthorized access